# angular ng-link parameter isn't working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making an angular shopping page which can be accessed through different links. So I am using angular parameter directives.  I want it to be `url/page/parameter` which I have got half working using this

controller:

```
var ShopController = (function () {
    function ShopController ($routeParams) {
        this.label = "Shop List";
        this.list = fullList;
        this.filter = $routeParams.id;
        this.setFilter = function (filter) {
            this.filter = filter;
        }
    }
    return ShopController ;
})();
app.controller("ShopController ", ['$routeParams',ShopController ]);
```

index link:

```
<a ng-class="{active: menu.isActive('/shop) }" ng-link="shop({id: 'prototype'})">
  Prototypes
</a>
```

routeController:

```
var RoutesController = (function () {
    /**
     * constructor
     * @param router: angular's new router service
     */
    function RoutesController($router) {
        this.$router = $router;
        $router.config([
            { path: '/', redirectTo: '/home' },
            { path: '/home', component: 'home' },
            { path: '/contact', component: 'contact' },
            { path: '/shop/:id', component: 'shop' }
        ]);
    }
    // static injection
    RoutesController.$inject = ["$router"];
    return RoutesController;
})();
// Add the controller to the application
app.controller("RoutesController", RoutesController);
```

When I load up, the page filter is set to undefined.  But when I debug the page, it seems to hit my shop 2ce. The first time filter is set to the routeparamer of `prototype`, but then before it even loads the page it hits the function again a second time and it clears the filter saying that route params is undefined.

Am I missing something here to get it to work?

Comment: Can this help? https://github.com/angular/router/issues/204 Looks like it's a bug in lib. And I cannot find doc for ngLink in angular docs..

Comment: well then... that is genuinely disappointing